# Communicating between a Chrome packaged app and a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I need to combine functionality available only in a Chrome packaged app (access to syncFileSystem) and functionality available only in a Chrome extension (injecting a script into a 3rd party website).

It seems that neither a packaged app nor an extension can achieve both these things, so I'm now considering trying to achieve what I'm after with a separate packaged app and extension communicating.

I see that [Chrome's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) explains how two *extensions* can communicate via `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener` and `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, but nothing about packaged apps and extensions communicating.

> Does anyone know if this is allowed? Is there any documentation, or a working example out there?

Answer (score 19):

Yes, that is possible. The code sample in the documentation you linked works for any combination of app and extension.

The extension documentation for [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage) says:

> Sends a single message to `onMessage` event listeners within the extension (**or another extension/app**).

Messaging works the same in both extensions and apps, and they seem to be fully compatible; simply use the ID for the destination extension or app. If you look at the docs for the [app version of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#event-onMessage), you'll see that it is identical to the extension version.

Comment: It would be really great to see how you end up bundling both the app and extension together. I'd like to be able to install them both with one click, ideally, but would settle for some kind of upsell from either one of the two to the other. And would detecting if the app is installed require it to be in background permission mode?

Comment: @mangini's link does not work anymore, but you can try: [https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/messaging](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/messaging).

Comment: @apsillers, Instead of making the user install both the app and the extension, is there anyway to combine them both into one unit such that the user only makes one installation action?