# Chrome Packaged App Access Chrome APIs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm interested in writing a Packaged App that can access data about chrome, namely the `chrome.windows.onCreated` and `chrome.windows.onRemoved` events. If I try to add a listener to either of these, I get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onRemoved' of undefined
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are correct that this isn't directly possible from a packaged app, but there is a solution that meets your needs:  You can write an extension as well as a packaged app and have them communicate with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

The user will have to install both app and extension, but you can make this easy by directing them to the chrome web store from within your application.  You can read about this here: [Communicating between a Chrome packaged app and a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015874/communicating-between-a-chrome-packaged-app-and-a-chrome-extension)

Edit: and as pointed out in a comment on that thread, there is a Chrome App Sample that helps demonstrate this in action: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/messaging

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. This allows me to do EXACTLY what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

The `chrome.windows` API is a Chrome extension API, not a packaged apps API. It is used by extensions to interact with browser windows.

If you can write your application as an extension, it will be able to use that API. Packaged apps, however, don't have the ability to manipulate other windows besides their own.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

One simple typo here: It is `chrome.windows.onRemoved` not `chrome.windows.OnRemoved` ;)

Note the lowercase `o`.

Comment: C# is creeping through. The typo is just because I typed it in here. It doesn't exist in my *.js file.