# Chrome Application - Interract with a tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to create an extension for Chrome, with a toolbox opened all the time. To achieve that, I figured that extensions doesn't allow to create such toolbox, so I'm trying to write a Chrome application, with a nice UI.

My problem is that in a chrome application, I can't access chrome.tabs, so I can't execute script in the window I want to parse.

Is there a way to do that with a chrome application ? Or is it possible to talk with another extension, which will execute script when requested by the application ?

EDIT: finally found [Communicating between a Chrome packaged app and a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015874/communicating-between-a-chrome-packaged-app-and-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: I don't think there is, not one that doesn't belong to you anyway otherwise extensions could scrape your banking etc. You can however either make a chrome app or show your tool box from the top right or open a new window

Comment: @kurt: when i mean communication with application and extension, i expect the application to have the permission to access/communicate with the extension, not the other apps. the problem of the top right extension is that it closes when you click in the body of the website. I dont see what you mean with create a new window (it's what we do with chrome application)

Comment: sorry I meaant new tab. Take a look at evernotes extension they seen to have gotten close. They have a right click menu but they seem to have gotten the top right menu as close as it gets.