# Can a Chrome App launch a window with a Chrome Extension active?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have written a Chrome extension and a Chrome packaged app. The extension uses the [chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onAuthRequired) extension API. I've installed this extension in Chrome.

When I create a window in the Chrome App with [chrome.app.window.create](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create), the extension is **not** active.

How can I launch a window from my Chrome App in which the extension is active?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use the `chrome.webRequest` API in my app, but I believe that is not possible.

Also, I understand that communication between a Chrome App and Chrome Extension is possible, (as in this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015874/communicating-between-a-chrome-packaged-app-and-a-chrome-extension)), but I really hope I won't have to use message passing, and I don't know if that would even work as I'm not sure I could get the app to recognize when authorization was being requested.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that chrome.webRequest is not possible? And why don't you want to use the sendMessage? It is clearly stated in the documentation that this is a one way to combine the chrome app and the extension.

Comment: I know that `chrome.webRequest` isn't possible to be used in an app because I tried using `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired` and received error **'Cannot read property 'onAuthRequired' of undefined**, and also documentation. 
You're right regarding messaging, it seems that is the stated way to combine extension and app capabilities, i was just hoping for an easier path I guess... but I'm still not sure if I am able to communicate with an extension in a window that is created with `chrome.window.create`